# Removing trailing zeros using REPLACE regex

Tags: regex, replace, abap

Remove trailing zeros to a number with 4 decimals

Sample expected output:

```
1.7500 -> 1.75

1.1010 -> 1.101

1.0000 -> 1
```

I am new with REGEX so I just tried this one first but not working:

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '^\.[0]\d{0,3}' IN lv_rate WITH space.
```

Need help for the right regex to use. Thanks!

**EDIT**: `SHIFT lv_rate RIGHT DELETING TRAILING '0'` is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing on the following regex pattern:

```
\.?0+$
```

Use empty string as the replacement.  This will match an optional decimal point, followed by trailing zeroes until the end of the string.  See the demo below to see this pattern working.

### Demo

This answer assumes that all inputs would always have a decimal component.  If not, then we would need to add additional logic.

Comment: @BrianJacobSanchez Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove trailing zeros to a number with 4 decimals, one option is to use a capturing group and use group 1 in the replacement.

```
^(\d+(?=\.\d{4}$)(?:\.\d*[1-9])?)\.?0+$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?=\.\d{4}$)` Assert what is on the right is a `.` and 4 digits
  - `(?:\.\d*[1-9])?` Optionally match digits until the last digit 1-9
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.?0+` Match an optional `.` and 1 or more times a zero
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OwKFUi/1)

Comment: @BrianJacobSanchez Note that the selected answer does not take 4 decimals into account and will for example also remove the last zero in 0-0

Comment: You should provide SAP code here, as lookaheads are probably not supported.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't have a quick solution to test SAP code, but form what I can find is that it supports [preview conditions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenregex_search.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SEARCH_6)